# Setting the props of a child component of a wrapper object in Vue

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, vue-component, vue-test-utils

I'm writing some tests using `vue-test-util` for a component I've made. I have boiled my code down to the actual problem.

The component is of the form:

```html
<template>
  <inner-component>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyList'
}
</script>
```

and my inner component looks something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="open">Some stuff</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'InnerComponent',
  props: {
    open: false,
  }
}
</script>
```

Now the test I'm writing is testing for the existence of the `div` in the `inner-component` when the `open` prop is set to `true`, but it is set to `false` by default. I need a way to set the prop of this child component before I test it.

My test:

```js
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import MyList from '@/components/MyList.vue'

describe('My Test', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue()
  const wrapper = mount(MyList)

  it('Tests', () => {
    // need to set the prop here
    expect(wrapper.find('div').exists()).toBeTruthy()
  }
}
```

I can use:

```js
wrapper.vm.$children[0].$options.propsData.open = true
```

Which does appear to set the prop, but my tests still come up as receiving false.

I can change the component so the default is true and then my tests pass so I don't think it's the way I'm checking.

If anyone can spot why this isn't working or knows a better way to come at it, please let me know!

Comment: Are you sure about the way you describe properties in `InnerComponent`? [Here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Types) they say that `props` as an object contains property names and their types, but not default values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options):

> **vm.$options**
>
> The instantiation options used for the current Vue instance.

So, `$options` is not what we write in `props`.

Use `$props` to set property for a child component:

```
wrapper.vm.$children[0].$props.open = true
```

But this way leads to the warning:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.

So, let's follow the advice and bind property of the child component with data of the parent component. Here I bind it with `isOpen` variable:

```
<template>
  <inner-component :open='isOpen'></inner-component>
</template>

<script>
import InnerComponent from '@/components/InnerComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'MyList',
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false
    }
  },
  components:{InnerComponent}
}
</script>
```

Then in your test, you can just change the value of `isOpen` when you want to change the value of `open` property in the child component:

```
    wrapper.setData({isOpen:true})
```

Comment: Thanks Lana this worked! It's complaining that I should `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten` but at this point I don't care aha

Comment: @Fergmux, I edited the answer and explained how to avoid the warning

Answer (score 3):

With the `vue-test-util` you can use the methods `setProps` from the wrapper, check the relative docs [here](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setprops)

For example

```
const wrapper = mount(Foo)
wrapper.setProps({ foo: 'bar' })
```

Comment: If you suppose MyList component instead of Foo, then you will set a property for a parent component, but not for a child component.

Comment: When using v2 I think it's important to note that you should `await wrapper.setProps({...})` before asserting.